# How to disable CKeditor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in my web application and need to disable/enable the editor from javascript. I know that there is an option called [readOnly](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.readOnly) but I don't know how to set it from jQuery.

Does anybody know how to disable and enable back the CKEditor using jQuery please?

Comment: does this help at all ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135892/how-can-i-close-ckeditor-or-tinymce-on-a-click-outside-of-the-editor

Comment: How can this be so damn difficult. :(

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way:

To **disable** CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['TEXTAREA_NAME'].setReadOnly(true);
```

To **enable** CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['TEXTAREA_NAME'].setReadOnly(false);
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly), `setReadOnly` is available since version 3.6.

Answer (score 11):

I am using it in codeigniter. In the view file I am using it like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        CKEDITOR.config.readOnly = true;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This won't cut it if you have many CKEditors on a single page and only some of them must be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the CKE's [jQuery adapter](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery), so you can use `.ckeditorGet()` jQuery function to quickly access the CKEditor's API.

To switch a running editor instance in read only mode, use the [**`setReadOnly`**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setReadOnly) editor function:

```
$( _your_textarea_ ).ckeditorGet().setReadOnly();
```

To switch it back into writable use:

```
.setReadOnly( false );
```

You can also use [**`readOnly`**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.readOnly) configuration value, when you are firing up your editor to start it in readonly mode right away:

```
$( _your_textarea_ ).ckeditor({
    readOnly: true
});
```

Comment: None of this seemed to work for me. Using version 3.5.2 best I can tell.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly), `setReadOnly` is available since version 3.6.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have included jQuery adapter following code should make it readonly.  You can take the jQuery adapter from the example if not yet included.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form id="myfrm" name="myfrm" class="myfrm" action="" method="post">
        <textarea id="myeditor" name="myeditor"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>​
```

and the js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var myeditor = $('#myeditor');
    myeditor.ckeditor();
    myeditor.ckeditorGet().config.resize_enabled = false;
    myeditor.ckeditorGet().config.height = 200;
    myeditor.ckeditorGet().config.readOnly = true;
});
```

To enable or disable a ckeditor based on your selection of a select box you'd have to make a change event like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //put ckeditor initialization (the above) here.
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
         var x = $(this);
         if(x.val()=='enable'){
             myeditor.removeAttr('disabled');           
         }else if(x.val()=='disable'){
             myeditor.attr('disabled','disabled');            
         }
         myeditor.ckeditorGet().destroy();
         myeditor.ckeditor();
    });
});
```

What we are doing above is setting the original element to have attribute `disabled="disabled"` and reloading ckeditor after destroying the current instance. Check the JSFiddle Example 2.

[JSFiddle Example to reflect OP's query](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/C5Ex4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't read that documentation properly...it says that Ckeditor has some instance name, and with that instance name in the  tag of the page set InstanceNameOfCkEditor.config.readOnly = true;

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setReadOnly

Comment: aren't you repeating what I said above?

Answer (score 1):

From: [cksource forums](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15659)

```
// Temporary workaround for providing editor 'read-only' toggling functionality. 
( function()
{
   var cancelEvent = function( evt )
      {
         evt.cancel();
      };

   CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.readOnly = function( isReadOnly )
   {
      // Turn off contentEditable.
      this.document.$.body.disabled = isReadOnly;
      CKEDITOR.env.ie ? this.document.$.body.contentEditable = !isReadOnly
      : this.document.$.designMode = isReadOnly ? "off" : "on";

      // Prevent key handling.
      this[ isReadOnly ? 'on' : 'removeListener' ]( 'key', cancelEvent, null, null, 0 );
      this[ isReadOnly ? 'on' : 'removeListener' ]( 'selectionChange', cancelEvent, null, null, 0 );

      // Disable all commands in wysiwyg mode.
      var command,
         commands = this._.commands,
         mode = this.mode;

      for ( var name in commands )
      {
         command = commands[ name ];
         isReadOnly ? command.disable() : command[ command.modes[ mode ] ? 'enable' : 'disable' ]();
         this[ isReadOnly ? 'on' : 'removeListener' ]( 'state', cancelEvent, null, null, 0 );
      }
   }
} )();
```

And usage:

```
// Turn CKEditor into 'ready-only' mode or vice versa.
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.readOnly( true );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.readOnly( false );
```

Answer (score 1):

I add a disabled to the textarea which seems to be the simplest way.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>HTML CONTENT</h3>
    <textarea name="editor1" disabled></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    </script>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are hiding the CKEditor and using a ReadOnlyText Area to display existing text. Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with this guy, until you find the right solution use this, approach, if you know how to gather the text inside the down side might be that you could end up exposing the HTML text as suppose to the real text, unless you strip tags and use appropriate spacing and new lines etc etc... or you could put it inside a div, so its properly formatted aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

you try this is the best solution

```html
 var existingEditor = CKEDITOR.instances && CKEDITOR.instances[element.id];
            try {
                if (existingEditor && typeof(existingEditor) !== "undefined" && typeof(existingEditor.setReadOnly) !== "undefined") {
                    if (el.prop("disabled")) {
                        existingEditor.setReadOnly(true);
                    } else {
                        existingEditor.setReadOnly(false);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                //do nothing
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple ckeditors on a page. Below solution worked for me.

```
   CKEDITOR.instances.instance_name.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
      var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.instance_name;

      //for disable
      editor.setReadOnly();

      //for enable
      editor.setReadOnly(false);    
                                                
    });
```