# How to enable and show entered data in CKEDITOR?

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

In one of my webpage i have a CKEDITOR and two images containing 'onclick' events.When the page loads the editor is **disabled**.First: I want to enable the editor by pressing the first image having title "Allow edit".However this does not work.

My second problem is, i am not able to show alert message of the data entered into the editor when i remove the disabled attribute. The codes i'm using are given below.Please advise.Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="../ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
.......
.......
       <img src="../images/allow_edit.gif" alt="" onclick="enableEdit();" class="smallThreeButtons"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Allow edit"/>&nbsp;
       <img src="../images/modify_this.gif" alt="" onclick="saveEditData('txtAreaFullStoryP1');" class="smallThreeButtons"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Save modification"/>&nbsp;
       <textarea class="form-control" id="txtAreaFullStoryP1" disabled name="txtAreaFullStoryP1"></textarea>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtAreaFullStoryP1', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
            filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
            filebrowserUploadUrl : '../ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '../ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
            filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '../ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
            });
            CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           function enableEdit(cs){
            document.getElementById('txtAreaFullStoryP1').disabled='';//false <--not working
           }

           function saveEditData(ctrlNm){
                var ctrl_val = document.getElementById(ctrlNm).value;
                alert(ctrl_val);//<--not working, showing blank message
            }
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.. And also read guidelines on how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove disable

```
document.getElementById('txtAreaFullStoryP1').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

get textarea data in CKEDITOR

```
var ctrl_val= CKEDITOR.instances['txtAreaFullStoryP1'].getData()
alert( ctrl_val);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..How to get textarea data in CKEditor is working but unfortunately the above disable code is not working

Comment: it says : Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined(…)

Comment: document.getElementById('txtAreaFullStoryP1').removeAttribute('disabled');

Answer (score 0):

To get data from CKEditor, the answer suggested by @Venkatesh worked for me.However for the enable/disable of the editor, a solution provided by@Dias in the same forum worked for me.
[How to disable CKeditor with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457071/how-to-disable-ckeditor-with-jquery)