# Is there any way to prevent someone from copying text from CKEDITOR using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

To prevent pasting into CKEditor below works for me.

```
window.CKEDITOR.instances.PEGACKEDITOR0.on('paste', function(evt){evt.cancel();})
```

Similarly is there any way to prevent someone from copying text from CKEditor using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

For all the document you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = preventing;


   function preventing () { 
 /* Disable right click on web page  */
     document.onclick("contextmenu",function(e){
     return false; }); 

/* Disable cut, copy and paste on web page */ 

document.bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); }); };

</script>
```

[Adapted from this source](https://www.codespeedy.com/disable-right-click-copy-cut-on-web-page-using-jquery/)

If you need only on the ckedit area:

```
var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'myElement' );
element.on( 'click', function( ev )
{
    // The DOM event object is passed by the "data" property.
    var domEvent = ev.data;
    // Prevent the click to chave any effect in the element.
    domEvent.stopPropagation();
})
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135892/how-can-i-close-ckeditor-or-tinymce-on-a-click-outside-of-the-editor)

Comment: I need to prevent CTRL+C. is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: document.bind('copy paste', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); });